# Banco de dados/servidor lento

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Estou iniciando na área de banco de dados e percebo uma grande lentidão em alguns bancos que utilizo em servidores virtuais.

No meu caso eu acesso um  windows que possui um postgres e com uma frequencia média meus scripts estão demorando muito para rodar...

Otimizei-os para que haja menos queries de alta consultas, verifico os discos rigidos, ram, internet e estão sempre ok.

Gostaria de uma recomendação para normalizar esta situação.

Comment: O que é uma query de alta consulta?

Comment: Penso que se refira a uma query que retorne uma grande quantidade de dados

Comment: Uma query que monta um arquivo .txt, que realiza update e insert em mais de 5.000 linhas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É uma pergunta bastante genérica. Ideal é que você monitore constantemente estatísticas de desempenho de seus bancos de dados e da infraestrutura que os suporta, assim pode medir o impacto das quedas de desempenho e correlacionar eventos que as possam ter causado, assim você ataca a origem do problema.

O que o Genivan disse na outra resposta é fato, você precisa manter seus VACUUMs e ANALYZEs rodando periodicamente, mas isso já é feito automaticamente pelo PostgreSQL e na maioria dos casos as configurações padrão são suficientes. Uma alteração nesses parâmetros deve ser feita com motivos, e para isso é necessário estudo do caso específico.

Algumas sugestões para você identificar melhor o que acontece com o seu banco:

1. Não sei qual versão do Postgres você está usando, mas não custa dizer: considere uma atualização de versão.
2. Aprenda a utilizar as *views* de estatísticas do PostgreSQL: [pg_stat_activity](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ACTIVITY-VIEW) para ver as *queries* que estão sendo executadas no momento presente; [pg_stat_bgwriter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-BGWRITER-VIEW) para ver como está o uso do buffer de memória do Postgres; [pg_stat_all_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STAT-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) (e *..._indexes*) para ver contagem de operações, últimas manutenções e outras estatísticas de suas tabelas e índices; [pg_statio_all_tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html#PG-STATIO-ALL-TABLES-VIEW) (e *..._indexes*) para ver estatísticas de uso de disco de suas tabelas e índices, [entre outras](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/monitoring-stats.html).
3. Aprenda a usar ferramentas de análise de log como o [pgBadger](http://dalibo.github.io/pgbadger/) e configure o parâmetro [log_line_prefix](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LINE-PREFIX) do Postgres para gerar metadados úteis para análise. Você pode utilizar o parâmetro [log_min_duration_statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT) para definir um tempo de *query* que considere aceitável, assim as execuções mais lentas são automaticamente registradas no log.
4. Ative outros parâmetros de log que possam te dar uma luz. Alguns exemplos: [log_checkpoints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-CHECKPOINTS) te ajuda identificar a saúde do seu buffer, [log_lock_waits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-LOCK-WAITS) te diz se suas *queries* estão concorrendo entre si, [log_temp_files](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-TEMP-FILES) te informa se muitos arquivos temporários estão sendo gerados pelas *queries*, o que indicaria memória insuficiente ou mal configurada.
5. Colete constantemente o uso de recursos de seu servidor: CPU, memória, I/O, volume de trocas de contexto, volume de memória alocada em cache de filesystem... Diversas ferramentas podem fazer isso, minha favorita é o bom e velho [sysstat](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/in-the-defense-of-sar/), com execuções periódicas do coletor `sar` agendadas na `crontab`. Não sei se há equivalente para Windows.
6. Considere utilizar o módulo *contrib* [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstatstatements.html), para coletar estatísticas de execução de suas *queries* em tempo real.

De posse dessas informações, há várias coisas que *talvez* você acabe descobrindo sobre seu uso do PostgreSQL, como por exemplo:

- A lentidão começa a acontecer após a execução de uma *query* específica que retorne muitos registros, concomitante a um aumento no volume de I/O, e melhora com o passar do tempo: pode significar que a *query* ofensora tome todo o [shared_buffers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-SHARED-BUFFERS) para ela e assim todas as outras precisem usar o disco de forma mais intensiva para realizar seu trabalho. Pode ser necessário aumentar o parâmetro, ou reescrever a *query*, particionar tabelas, etc. de forma a utilizar menos memória.
- A contenção ocorre sempre nos mesmos horários: pode haver alguma tarefa agendada que tome todos os recursos do banco para ela, ou gere *locks* em objetos fazendo com que suas outras *queries* esperem sua liberação.
- O tempo de espera por I/O aumenta significativamente sem que haja necessariamente um grande volume de trabalho para executar, e sua solução de armazenamento é compartilhada com outros servidores: outra de suas VMs está usando esse recurso físico, sem deixar nada para o seu PostgreSQL.
- O volume de arquivos temporários gerado por suas *queries* lentas é muito grande durante a lentidão, que por sua vez ocorre "no final do expediente", antes de eventuais rotinas de expurgo: o parâmetro [work_mem](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) pode estar subdimensionado, sendo necessário uso de disco para manipular grandes volumes de dados quando as tabelas estão mais "cheias".
- *Queries* corretas em tabelas bem indexadas estão preferindo *sequential scans* em vez de *index scans*: pode ser que o planejador do banco esteja com estatísticas de cardinalidade muito antigas, indício de que não estão sendo feitos muitos ANALYZEs nessa tabela.

São infinitas as possíveis causas quando se fala em lentidão de bancos de dados, pois são muitos os fatores envolvidos. A minha intenção com esta resposta foi, sobretudo, **deixar claro a importância de coletar estatísticas de desempenho e de conhecer o ambiente com que se está trabalhando**.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado pelas respostas e pelos toques.

Eu descobri que tinha uma aplicação que utilizava uma querie que sobrecarregava o banco, porém, não sei como não "estourava" memória da maquina... Enfim, foi reformulada e melhorou cerca de 35% do desempenho do bd. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Sozinho dificilmente o PostgreSQL vai estourar a memória do servidor por causa de uma query, a não ser que esteja mal configurado, porque o que passar do `work_mem` vira arquivo temporário em disco. O desempenho cai, mas a execução continua. Que bom que encontrou o motivo do problema aí =)

Answer (score 0):

No Postgres, pode ser necessário rodar periodicamente os comandos Vacuum e Analyze para melhorar a performance do banco. Veja essa documentação:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-vacuum.html

Outra coisa que pode ser verificada, neste caso vale para qualquer BD, é a necessidade de criação de índices, geralmente em tabelas com milhares ou milhões de registros, mas como isso depende de uma análise, sugiro que você também procure artigos sobre esse assunto e faça uso deste recurso com parcimônia pois ao mesmo tempo que os Selects podem ficar mais rápidos, os inserts e updates podem ficar mais lentos.

Comment: Cara, obrigado pelos toques!
Conforme disse para o nunks.lol descobri uma query em uma aplicação que utilizava muito do banco, e, porfim otimizamos e isso afetou em cerca de 35% de melhora de desenpenho do bd.
Abs!